# Python Pandas showing change in position between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, valueerror

I am reading two dataframes looking at one column and then showing the difference in position between the two dataframe with a -1 or +1 etc.
I have try the following code but it only shows `0` in Position Change when there should be a difference between British Airways and Ryanair

```
first = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\airma\\PycharmProjects\\Vatsim_Stats\\Vatsim_stats\\Base.csv", encoding='unicode_escape')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(first, columns=['airlines', 'Position'])
second = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\airma\\PycharmProjects\\Vatsim_Stats\\Vatsim_stats\\Base2.csv", encoding='unicode_escape')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(second, columns=['airlines', 'Position'])

df1['Position Change'] = np.where(df1['airlines'] == df2['airlines'], 0, df1['Position'] - df2['Position'])
```

I have also try to do it with the following code, but just keep getting a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

```
df1.set_index('airlines', drop=False)  # Set index to cross reference by (icao)
df2.set_index('airlines', drop=False)
df2['Position Change'] = df1[['Position']].sub(df2['Position'], axis=0)  
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)  
pd.set_option('display.precision', 0)
```

Base csv looks like this -
[image]

and Base2 csv looks like this - [image]

As you can see British Airways is in 3 position on Base csv and 4 in Base 2 csv, but when running the code it just shows `0` and does not do the math between the two dataframes.
Have been stuck on this for days now, would be so grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer some easier way based on columns, value and if-statement.
It is probably a little bit useless while you have big dataframe, but it can gives you the information you expect.

```
first = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\airma\\PycharmProjects\\Vatsim_Stats\\Vatsim_stats\\Base.csv", encoding='unicode_escape')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(first, columns=['airlines', 'Position'])
second = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\airma\\PycharmProjects\\Vatsim_Stats\\Vatsim_stats\\Base2.csv", encoding='unicode_escape')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(second, columns=['airlines', 'Position'])
```

I agree, that my answer was not correct with your question.
Now, if I understand correctly - you want to create new column in DataFrame that gives you -1 if two same columns in 2 DataFrames are incorrect and 1 if correct.

It should help:

```
key = "Name_Of_Column"
new = []
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    if df1[key][i] != df2[key][i]:
        new.append(-1)
    else:
        new.append(1)

df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Diff":new}) # I create new DataFrame as Dictionary.
df1 = df1.append(df3, ignore_index = True)
print(df1)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but all your code does is tell me what rows do not match. What I need is a new column to be created called `Position change` which shows me how much in the dataframe it has moved up or down, for example show a -1 or +1.

Answer (score 0):

i am giving u an alternative, i am not sure whether it is appreciated or not. But just an idea.

After reading two csv's and getting the column u require, why don't you try to join two dataframes for the column'airlines'? it will merge two dataframes with key as 'airlines'

Comment: I do appreciate you answer, but that does not help me. What I am after is seeing the difference in position for the airlines between the old csv and the new csv, then showing that position change in a new column called `Position Change` . Your answer just merges the one column.